# Client-Server Chat App - Messages are duplicating within the fwd_all and add_user methods but how do I resolve?

Tags: java, sockets, debugging, duplicates, client-server

As stated above, my problem is within the two methods add user and fwd all where I have done some debugging and found the duplications are caused there, I would like to know if there is anywhere else in my source code that is causing abnormal functionalities?

Below is the source code of the server class where I can confirm that is the root of the problem:

```
public class TCP_Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<String> C_Username; // Arraylist of users connected to the server

    ArrayList C_OutStream; // Preparing Arraylist of output streams to client

    /**
     * Constructor to initialise the jFrame via 'generated code'.
     */
    public TCP_Server() {
        initComponents();
        Chat_LogS.setEditable(false); // textarea not interactable
    }

    /**
     * Client handler uses the interface 'Runnable' for multi-threading to
     * provide responsiveness in the snippet of code below that connect or
     * disconnect clients while processes operate 'concurrently'.
     */
    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

        BufferedReader from_Client; // Data buffer from client
        Socket connection; // Part of communication channel
        PrintWriter client; // format data as text (UTF-8)

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, PrintWriter user) {
            client = user;
            try {
                /* Opens the communication channel */
                connection = clientSocket;

                /* Prepares the input streams */
                InputStreamReader in_Client = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                from_Client = new BufferedReader(in_Client);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                /* If communication isn't successful */
                Chat_LogS.append("Unexpected exception occurerd \n");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Method of Runnable interface for 'thread safe operation' of connect
         * or disconnect users from the chat.
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Correspond to dialogue provided in the if statement */
            String msg;
            String connect = "Connect";
            String disconnect = "Disconnect";
            String chat = "Chat";
            String[] data;

            /* Enclosed in try catch block, server is to reply to client */
            try {
                while ((msg = from_Client.readLine()) != null) {
                    /* Response of server in textarea */
                    Chat_LogS.append("Received: " + msg + "\n");

                    /* Split array of string to substrings via ':' */
                    data = msg.split(":");

                    for (String token : data) {
                        Chat_LogS.append(token + "\n");
                    }

                    /* If statement for corresponding words declared above */
                    // Here are squiggly lines due to absent long data type...
                    if (data[2].equals(connect)) {
                        fwd_All((data[0] + ":" + data[1] + ":" + chat));
                        Add_User(data[0]);
                    } else if (data[2].equals(disconnect)) {
                        fwd_All((data[0] + ":has left the chat" + ":" + chat));
                        Remove_User(data[0]);
                    } else if (data[2].equals(chat)) {
                        fwd_All(msg);
                    } else {
                        Chat_LogS.append("No condition is met \n");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Chat_LogS.append("Connection for a user is lost \n");
                C_OutStream.remove(client);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Auto generated code can be modified in JFrame */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Chat_LogS = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        Start_Btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Online_Btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Clear_Btn = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Server Frame");
        setName("server"); // NOI18N
        setResizable(false);

        Chat_LogS.setColumns(20);
        Chat_LogS.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Chat_LogS);

        Start_Btn.setText("Start Server");
        Start_Btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Start_BtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Online_Btn.setText("Online Users");
        Online_Btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Online_BtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Clear_Btn.setText("Clean Page");
        Clear_Btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Clear_BtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(Start_Btn)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(Online_Btn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(Clear_Btn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 265, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Clear_Btn)
                    .addComponent(Online_Btn)
                    .addComponent(Start_Btn))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /* Available to open communication channel and accept client(s) request */
    private void Start_BtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Thread starter = new Thread(new ServerStart());
        starter.start();
        Chat_LogS.append("*Server is Activated* \n");
    }                                         

    /* Print in the server chat log: list of users connected to chat server */
    private void Online_BtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        Chat_LogS.append("Online users: \n");
        for (String current_user : C_Username) {
            Chat_LogS.append(current_user + "\n");
        }
    }                                          

    /* Clean 'slate' of the server chat log */
    private void Clear_BtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Chat_LogS.setText("");
    }                                         

    /* Main method to execute the server class UI */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TCP_Server().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Did I do anything wrong in here? 
    public class ServerStart implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            C_OutStream = new ArrayList();
            C_Username = new ArrayList();

            long id = 1L;

            try {             
                /* Opens the communication channel */
                ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(1183);

                while (true) {
                    /* Accepting client request */
                    Socket clientSock = serverSock.accept();

                    /* Sending response to client */
                    PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                    C_OutStream.add(wr);

                    /* Communicates with client handler class - accepting connections*/                                
                    Thread listener = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSock, wr));
                    listener.start();
                    Chat_LogS.append("Connection Successful \n");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Chat_LogS.append("Experiencing Connectivity Issues \n");
            }
        }
    }

    /* Server approves new client to join the chatroom */
        // Made changes here for the ID
    public void Add_User(String data) {
        String msg;
        String add = ": :Connect";
        String done = "Server: :Done";
        String name = data;

        C_Username.add(name);

        Chat_LogS.append("New member: " + name + " has joined \n");
        String[] tempList = new String[(C_Username.size())];
        C_Username.toArray(tempList);

        for (String tkn : tempList) {
            msg = (tkn + add);
            fwd_All(msg);
        }
        fwd_All(done);
    }

    /* Sever approves of client request to be removed from chat room */
    // Made changes here for the ID
    public void Remove_User(String data) {
        String msg;
        String add = ": :Connect";
        String done = "Server: :Done";
        String name = data;

        C_Username.remove(name);
        String[] tempList = new String[(C_Username.size())];
        C_Username.toArray(tempList);

        for (String token : tempList) {
            msg = (token + add);
            fwd_All(msg);
        }
        fwd_All(done);
    }

    /* Iterates to all clients connected to the server */
    // This is a problem; it sends same dialogue twice!!!

        // I dont know if the implementation is done correct.
    public void fwd_All(String msg) {
        Iterator it = C_OutStream.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            try {
                PrintWriter wr = (PrintWriter) it.next();
                wr.println(msg); // Recipient of message
                Chat_LogS.append("Sending to: " + msg + "\n");
                wr.flush();
                //Chat_LogS.setCaretPosition(Chat_LogS.getDocument().getLength());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Chat_LogS.append("Error forwarding message \n");
            }
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea Chat_LogS;
    private javax.swing.JButton Clear_Btn;
    private javax.swing.JButton Online_Btn;
    private javax.swing.JButton Start_Btn;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here are the outputs that are produced in the server log after new users are connected in the chatroom:

```
// When second user connects
Connection Successful 
Received: Vincent:has connected:Connect
Vincent
has connected
Connect
Sending to: Vincent:has connected:Chat
Sending to: Vincent:has connected:Chat
New member: Vincent has joined 
Sending to: Bruce: :Connect
Sending to: Bruce: :Connect
Sending to: Vincent: :Connect
Sending to: Vincent: :Connect
Sending to: Server: :Done
Sending to: Server: :Done
```

Thanks to sudipn I have found the solution which was because of the chatlogS append being inside the while loop of forwarding the messages:

Here is the change made:

```
/* Iterates to all clients connected to the server */
public void fwd_All(String msg) {
    Iterator it = C_OutStream.iterator();

    Chat_LogS.append("Forwarding Message: " + msg + "\n"); // NEW
    Chat_LogS.setCaretPosition(Chat_LogS.getDocument().getLength()); //NEW

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
            PrintWriter wr = (PrintWriter) it.next();
            wr.println(msg); // Recipient of message
            wr.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Chat_LogS.append("Error forwarding message \n");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output now:

```
Connection Successful 
Received: Bruce:has connected:Connect
Forwarding Message: Bruce:has connected:Chat
New member: Bruce has joined 
Forwarding Message: Vincent: :Connect
Forwarding Message: Bruce: :Connect
Forwarding Message: Server: :Done
```

Even with the sending of messages:

```
Received: Bruce:Hello:Chat
Forwarding Message: Bruce:Hello:Chat
Received: Vincent:Greetings:Chat
Forwarding Message: Vincent:Greetings:Chat
```

Comment: well the update does fixes the log on the server side, but the messages are still sent multiple times to the client. Is it intended?

Comment: Yes that is intended because a message for the recipient of whom sent the message, an the same message being forward to all other connected clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your bug are the two loops:

- The first one `for (String tkn : tempList) {` in the `Add_User`
- And the second one `while (it.hasNext()) {` inside `fwd_All`

From the first loop, a call is made to the `fwd_All` where the second loop runs.

When there is only one element in the array (the user *Bruce*), the `for` loop in `Add_User` run once and in this run it calls the `fwd_All` where the `while` loop also runs once.

Now when there are two elements in the `C_Username` array (*Bruce* and *Vincent*), the `for` loop in `Add_User` method runs twice. In the first run of the `for` loop with user *Bruce*, it calls the `fwd_All` and now in this method the while loop iterates twice (because there are two entries in `C_Outstream`). Therefore you see duplicate outputs. Once the while loop finishes, the control moves back to the `for` loop where it runs for the second user which then again calls the `fwd_All` method and the iterator runs twice.

debug your code to get a better understanding. I hope this explains why you have ever increasing number of logs.

Comment: i have updated my answers with where you exactly have to change your code. And yes you are right, it is the accessor method.

Comment: i am sorry, i have got it completely wrong. can you please undo your changes. i will have another look

Comment: Hey sudipn, thank you for the suggestion of where I should be debugging my code but I still am very much unsure of if there is anywhere else in my source code that is causing abnormal functionalities to my program. such as the arraylist for storing usernames and outputstreams.

Comment: sorry I disagree with you, my post above specifically answers the question you asked in your title - why messages are duplicating. And as said, this is because of the two loops going through your two lists (username, outputstreams).

Comment: I have done some careful debugging an If I am correct, the two arraylists are "overlapping each other" - I noticed that first in index 0 would be the username, then in index 1 is the outputstream - would it be better off to use a different data structure that could handle duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

a hint: the two array list (`C_Username`, `C_OutStream`) are correlated with each other. So a quick fix would be:

```java
public void Add_User(String data) {
    String msg;
    String add = ": :Connect";
    String done = "Server: :Done";
    String name = data;

    C_Username.add(name);
    Chat_LogS.append("New member: " + name + " has joined \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < C_Username.size(); i++) {
        PrintWriter wr = C_OutStream[i]; 
        msg = C_Username[i] + add;
        fwd(msg, wr);
        fwd(done, wr);
    }
}

private void fwd(String msg, PrintWriter wr) {
    try {
        wr.println(msg); // Recipient of message
        Chat_LogS.append("Sending to: " + msg + "\n");
        wr.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Chat_LogS.append("Error forwarding message \n");
    }
}
```

similar for `Remove_User`.

Comment: That is true it is one way of solving the problem, I have found another solution which I found it was because of the chat log appending inside the while loop - therefore I put it outside of the while loop and it resolved my program - Check for updated solution and results